# How to write a function multiple(5)(6) that will return 30?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand how can we achieve such a function in JS, and what is the main use of this approach?

multiple(5) will return 5 
multiple(5)(6) will return 30

how can we achieve such a function in JavaScript?

Comment: Hint: `multiple` will return a function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: "currying" is the keyword for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `valueOf` and function that return a function.
Here: `multiple(5)` will return 5 `multiple(5)(6)` will return 30

```
function multiple(x){
    function func(y){
    return x*y
  }
  func.valueOf=function(){return x}
  return func
}
```

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k9meraL6/

```
alert(multiple(5)(6)) //30 
alert(multiple(5) + 1) //6
```

### More info:

#### Valueof

> JavaScript calls the valueOf method to convert an object to a primitive value

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

Comment: If your answer is downvoted, deleting it and reposting it is **not** the correct response. *(not my dv)*

Comment: Why would you use `valueOf`?

Comment: what about  alert(multiple(5)) :P

Comment: T.J. Crowder, Your right, It was by mistake, I edited the question, and instead, it created a new answer, so I have to delete one of my answers. Anyway, You are welcome to downvote it again.

Comment: *"I edited the question, and instead it created a new answer"* Eight years and more on SO, never once has the site magically decided that an edit was a new answer.

Comment: @oniondomes: So that `multiply(5)` would seem to give the value 5 while really returning a function.

Comment: T.J.Crowder,  after years here on SO it never happened to me either, today
after editing a question, I clicked the "back" button of the browser, and it goes back to editing a question, but when I posted it, it created a new answer.

Comment: @Aminadav: Even **if** that's true (and I find it very hard to believe with a site like SO), so you delete the new one. Whatever. Moving on.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it returning a function but it behaves like a number in calculations.

Comment: Right. That's what I said above when oniondomes asked why you were using it.